# Cap'n Proto Generics How To?

Tags: javascript, typescript, capnproto

For the life of my I can't figure out how to get this to work.
This is the structure

```
//transaction.capnp
using V = import "values.capnp";
struct TransactionPayload {
    kwargs @6 :V.Map(Text, V.Value);
}

//values.capnp
struct Map(Key, Value) {
  entries @0 :List(Entry);
  struct Entry {
    key @0 :Key;
    value @1 :Value;
  }
}
```

I've read as much to understand this to be a "generics" structure.

I'm trying to implement it in typescript using capnp-ts.

I cannot figure out how to set the "Text" portion of the Map.  I can get Value done as it's just a matter of initRoot(mystructs.Value), but I have no "Text" struct to use, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to create for that.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.  Sharing for those interested.

```
        let keyMessage = new capnp.Message().initRoot(capnp.Text);
        keyMessage.set(0, 'foo')
        this.kwargEntries.get(0).setKey(keyMessage)
```